# Deleting a version from a custom list item will only remove the data inside field/s with "Append Changes to Existing Text = Yes"

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, versioning, version-history

I am working on custom list inside SharePoint online, and the list have major versions turned on. so now when i click on the date inside a field which have "Append Changes to Existing Text = Yes" >> i will have an option to Delete this version as follow:-

[image]

but what i though will happen is that all the data entered at the deleted version will be removed, but what is happening is that only the fields which have "Append Changes to Existing Text = Yes" will have their data removed. so can anyone advice if this behavior is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue you are facing. It is default SharePoint behavior. When you delete a version, the value from append only column gets deleted but the values of the other columns are updated to the values in the current active version and the entries that these columns are updated with current values is added to the latest version of that item.

If you want the values of other columns to be deleted and assigned previous values, then it is recommended to restore to a previous version (version previous to the one you want to delete) and then delete the version. This way the values of other columns that were changed are back to previous values and you will be able to delete the version.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior for “Append Changes to Existing Text” feature.

This feature is only available for *Multiple lines of text* column and is only responsible for values of this column.

If you want to remove all data of this version, select item and click ITEMS > Version History > menu of the specific version > Delete. It will remove the entry of the column on this version as well.

[image]