# Restoring previous version of a SharePoint list item retains subsequent 'appended' values

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, version-history

I have a list with two fields that have these settings:

`Multiple Lines of Text` (`Plain Text`)
`Append Changes to Existing Text` (`Yes`)

Example:

```
Condition Comments:    

General Comments:
```

I started with this:

```
Condition Comments:    

General Comments:   Here is a general comment
```

And then I mistakenly appended a value to the `Condition Comments` field instead of the `General Comments` field, ie:

```
Condition Comments:  Here is another general comment  

General Comments:   Here is a general comment
```

I went to the item's `Version History` and selected `v 1.0` to `Restore`.

However it has kept and duplicated the `Condition Comments` values, ie:

```
Condition Comments:  Here is another general comment  
                     Here is another general comment 

General Comments:   Here is a general comment
```

I tried this process several times and now have something like this:

```
Condition Comments:  Here is another general comment  
                     Here is another general comment 

General Comments:   Here is a general comment
                    Here is a general comment
                    Here is a general comment
```

How can I get back to the version prior to the mistake, ie `v1.0` and *not* keep the subsequent changes that were made since that version?

I want to end up with this:

```
Condition Comments:    

General Comments:   Here is a general comment
```

**Edit**

I don't understand it yet, but it looks like these articles and questions are related:

[Problem restoring a list item version and comment history (2010)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/59035f68-4b16-4947-809a-6dfa612e0475/problem-restoring-a-list-item-version-and-comment-history?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

[Deleting a version from a custom list item will only remove the data inside field/s with “Append Changes to Existing Text = Yes”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275699/deleting-a-version-from-a-custom-list-item-will-only-remove-the-data-inside-fiel)

*Related reading:*

[How versioning works in lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-versioning-works-in-lists-and-libraries-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247)

**Edit 2**

When i try and delete the undesired versions, I get this message:

> Sorry, something went wrong
> Versions of this item cannot be deleted because it is on hold or retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you enable the feature Append Changes to Existing Text for a field in a SharePoint list item, changes to that field are shown as a thread. So when you restore previous version the new text is shown above the earlier text. You could delete the wrong version.

For this error message, you could check you retention policy in Microsoft 365 admin center.

For Reference:
[Error - Version of this item cannot be deleted because it’s on hold or retention – SPO/ Office 365 SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/version-of-this-item-be-deleted-because-its-on-hold-or-retention-spo-office-365-sharepoint)